# implode some variables in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

i have a some variables like this

```
string cond;

if(cond1){
    cond += "name=@name";
}

if(cond2){
    cond += "age=@age";

}

if(cond3){
    cond += "city=@city";
}


query="select * from students where"+string.Join("  and ",cond);
```

i want to do this

```
query="select * from students where if exists cond1 (cond) and if exists cond2 (cond)";
```

i want implode all conds into one variable with cond(and) .

Comment: You mean "combine" into one variable? It doesn't make much sense to split.. into one..

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Manipulating raw SQL is dangerous and can easily lead to injection attacks. You without be better off using an ORM

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Kane Basically: yes. In General: no. It always depends on *if you know, what you are doing*

Comment: yes combine .but with cond (and ) between variables .I'm beginning to learn c# . you can write me how another way make this !

Comment: i want make advanced search . i have four combo-boxes and i want filter data in the datagrideview based on selected value in comboboxes

Comment: @Kane there's no sql injection risk here, OP is using parameters. How do you think ORM code works if not by dynamically building SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, to answer your question, you can do something like this to build your clause:

```
List<string> conditions = new List<String>();

if (cond1) { 
   conditions.Add("name=@name");
}

if (cond2) { /* etc.. */ }

string query = "select * from students";
if (conditions.Any()) { 
   query += " where " + string.Join(" AND ", conditions);
}
```

Although, with Linq, you can build your query dynamically and protect yourself from sql injection.

```
IQueryable<Student> students = myDataContext.Students; //eg DbSet<Students>

if (cond1) { 
   students = students.Where(s => s.Name == "Adam");
}

if (cond2) { 
   students = students.Where(s => s.Age > 20);
}

var matchedStudents = students.ToList();
```

When you call .ToList(), you will iterate the IQueryable and the resulting sql query will contain all the relevant `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: there error !. query like this ( select * from students wherename=@name) not space between where and name into query !

Comment: There's no SQL injection risk in the SQL building code either, since OP appears to be using parameters.

Answer (score 1):

```
string cond;

if(cond1){
    cond += "name=@name";
}

if(cond2){
    cond += "age=@age";

}

if(cond3){
    cond += "city=@city";
}
```

This will give you a String like `name=@nameage=@agecity=@city` because you are just APPENDING Strings.

if you want to use the `String.Join()` Operator, you need to push the single parts to a `List<String>`, like so:

```
List<string> cond = new List<string>();

if(cond1){
    cond.add("name=@name");
}

if(cond2){
    cond.add("age=@age");

}

if(cond3){
    cond.add("city=@city");
}

query="select * from students where"+string.Join(" AND ",cond.ToArray());
```

Will result in

```
"select * from students where name=@name AND age=@age AND city=@city"
```

Comment: i get error with query ! query like this "select * from students wherename=@name" not space between where and name into query

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
List<string> conds = new List<string>();

if(cond1){
    conds.Add("name=@name");
}

if(cond2){
    conds.Add("age=@age");
}

if(cond3){
    conds.Add("city=@city");
}

query="select * from students where " + string.Join(" and ", conds.ToArray());
```

I have assumed that there will always be at least one condition (otherwise, you'll get `select * from students where` - invalid SQL syntax).

Since it looks like you are using parameters already (good!), you can also track the parameters alongside the SQL conditions.

Add a `List<SqlParameter>` and fill it out as you go:

```
List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();

if (cond1) {
    conds.Add("name=@name");
    parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name") { Value = text1.Text; });
}
// etc.

// later..
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
```

Comment: there error ! query like this "select * from students wherename=@name" not space between where and name into query

Comment: @adam my code says `query="select * from students where "`, with a space after the `where`. Does yours have the space?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL the use a case statement

```
SELECT CASE(@intCode) 
              WHEN 1 THEN 'Country_1'
              WHEN 2 THEN 'Country_2'
              WHEN 3 THEN 'Country_3'
              WHEN 4 THEN 'Country_4'
              WHEN 5 THEN 'Country_5'
              WHEN 6 THEN 'Country_6'
              WHEN 7 THEN 'Country_7'
              WHEN 8 THEN 'Country_8'
              WHEN 9 THEN 'Country_9'
              WHEN 10 THEN 'Country_10'         
                      ELSE 'Unknown' END
```